# Как проверить отказано в доступе к запоминающему устройству(флешка) или нет через c#?

Tags: c#, windows, usb, wmi

пишу программу по мониторингу подключаемых устройств и нужно сделать некие действия, если флешка будет заблокирована(отказано в доступе, за блокировку флешек отвечает стороннее ПО). Как проверить есть ли доступ к флешке или нет? Не могу найти способ или плохо ищу...

Comment: Наверно прочитать/записать файл и обработать исключение?

Comment: Да до этого тоже додумался, спасибо. Но думал, может методы есть какие для проверки доступа просто